# XAMPP: I edited PHP.ini, and now Apache crashes

Tags: apache, xdebug, php

I'm trying to set up XDebug for PHP. I edited some settings in my `apache\bin\php.ini` file, and now Apache crashes every couple page requests. (I wish I had saved a copy of php.ini before editing it. der.)

I was following instructions here: http://robsnotebook.com/php_debugger_pdt_xdebug

Here is the only section I changed. Does anything stand out as causing a problem?

I removed the "local variables" stuff, but it's still having issues.

```
[Zend]
; zend_extension_ts = "C:\xampp\php\zendOptimizer\lib\ZendExtensionManager.dll"
;zend_extension_manager.optimizer_ts = "C:\xampp\php\zendOptimizer\lib\Optimizer"
;zend_optimizer.enable_loader = 0
;zend_optimizer.optimization_level=15
;zend_optimizer.license_path =

[XDebug]
;; Only Zend OR (!) XDebug
 zend_extension_ts="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.0.5-5.2.dll"
 xdebug.remote_enable=true
 xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
 xdebug.remote_port=9000
 xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
 xdebug.profiler_enable=0
 xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\xampp\tmp"
```

Here is the Apache error log from my flailing around: (Not all of these errors were generated from the above configuration.)

```
[Sat Oct 17 15:12:28 2009] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sat Oct 17 15:12:28 2009] [notice] Child 2692: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Sat Oct 17 15:12:29 2009] [notice] Child 2692: Released the start mutex
[Sat Oct 17 15:12:30 2009] [notice] Child 2692: All worker threads have exited.
[Sat Oct 17 15:12:31 2009] [notice] Child 2692: Child process is exiting
[Sat Oct 17 15:12:47 2009] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.
[Sat Oct 17 15:12:56 2009] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Oct 17 15:12:56 2009] [notice] Digest: done
PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Oct 17 15:12:57 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8i mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.2.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Oct 17 15:12:57 2009] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
[Sat Oct 17 15:12:57 2009] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4648
[Sat Oct 17 15:12:58 2009] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Oct 17 15:12:58 2009] [notice] Digest: done
PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Oct 17 15:12:58 2009] [notice] Child 4648: Child process is running
[Sat Oct 17 15:12:58 2009] [notice] Child 4648: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sat Oct 17 15:12:58 2009] [notice] Child 4648: Starting 250 worker threads.
[Sat Oct 17 15:12:58 2009] [notice] Child 4648: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Sat Oct 17 15:12:58 2009] [notice] Child 4648: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Sat Oct 17 15:13:24 2009] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Sat Oct 17 15:13:46 2009] [warn] pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Oct 17 15:13:46 2009] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Oct 17 15:13:46 2009] [notice] Digest: done
PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Oct 17 15:13:46 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8i mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.2.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Oct 17 15:13:46 2009] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
[Sat Oct 17 15:13:46 2009] [notice] Parent: Created child process 6232
[Sat Oct 17 15:13:47 2009] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Oct 17 15:13:47 2009] [notice] Digest: done
PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Oct 17 15:13:47 2009] [notice] Child 6232: Child process is running
[Sat Oct 17 15:13:47 2009] [notice] Child 6232: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sat Oct 17 15:13:47 2009] [notice] Child 6232: Starting 250 worker threads.
[Sat Oct 17 15:13:47 2009] [notice] Child 6232: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Sat Oct 17 15:13:48 2009] [notice] Child 6232: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Sat Oct 17 15:13:57 2009] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Sat Oct 17 15:16:31 2009] [warn] pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Oct 17 15:16:31 2009] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Oct 17 15:16:31 2009] [notice] Digest: done
PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Oct 17 15:16:32 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8i mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.2.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Oct 17 15:16:32 2009] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
[Sat Oct 17 15:16:32 2009] [notice] Parent: Created child process 480
[Sat Oct 17 15:16:32 2009] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Oct 17 15:16:32 2009] [notice] Digest: done
PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Oct 17 15:16:33 2009] [notice] Child 480: Child process is running
[Sat Oct 17 15:16:33 2009] [notice] Child 480: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sat Oct 17 15:16:33 2009] [notice] Child 480: Starting 250 worker threads.
[Sat Oct 17 15:16:33 2009] [notice] Child 480: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Sat Oct 17 15:16:33 2009] [notice] Child 480: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Sat Oct 17 15:17:20 2009] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Sat Oct 17 15:18:30 2009] [warn] pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Oct 17 15:18:30 2009] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Oct 17 15:18:30 2009] [notice] Digest: done
PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Oct 17 15:18:30 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8i mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.2.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Oct 17 15:18:30 2009] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
[Sat Oct 17 15:18:30 2009] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3148
[Sat Oct 17 15:18:31 2009] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Oct 17 15:18:31 2009] [notice] Digest: done
PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Oct 17 15:18:31 2009] [notice] Child 3148: Child process is running
[Sat Oct 17 15:18:31 2009] [notice] Child 3148: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sat Oct 17 15:18:31 2009] [notice] Child 3148: Starting 250 worker threads.
[Sat Oct 17 15:18:31 2009] [notice] Child 3148: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Sat Oct 17 15:18:31 2009] [notice] Child 3148: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Sat Oct 17 15:18:41 2009] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Sat Oct 17 15:32:52 2009] [warn] pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Oct 17 15:32:52 2009] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Oct 17 15:32:52 2009] [notice] Digest: done
PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  [Zend Optimizer] Zend Optimizer 3.3.3 is incompatible with Xdebug 2.0.5 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Oct 17 15:33:03 2009] [warn] pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Oct 17 15:33:03 2009] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Oct 17 15:33:03 2009] [notice] Digest: done
PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  [Zend Optimizer] Zend Optimizer 3.3.3 is incompatible with Xdebug 2.0.5 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Oct 17 15:33:15 2009] [warn] pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Oct 17 15:33:15 2009] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Oct 17 15:33:15 2009] [notice] Digest: done
PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Oct 17 15:33:16 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8i mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.2.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Oct 17 15:33:16 2009] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
[Sat Oct 17 15:33:16 2009] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3336
[Sat Oct 17 15:33:17 2009] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Oct 17 15:33:17 2009] [notice] Digest: done
PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Oct 17 15:33:17 2009] [notice] Child 3336: Child process is running
[Sat Oct 17 15:33:17 2009] [notice] Child 3336: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sat Oct 17 15:33:17 2009] [notice] Child 3336: Starting 250 worker threads.
[Sat Oct 17 15:33:17 2009] [notice] Child 3336: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Sat Oct 17 15:33:17 2009] [notice] Child 3336: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Sat Oct 17 15:33:34 2009] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/xampp/security/htdocs/lang.php, referer: http://localhost/xampp/navi.php
[Sat Oct 17 15:33:50 2009] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
```

Comment: What does the Apache log have to say?

I haven't seen Local variables: directive before, what is it?

Comment: Where might I find the Apache log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
zend_optimizer.license_path =
 Local Variables:
 tab-width: 4
 End:
```

Is definitely not valid part of `php.ini`. Looks like some leftover from your text editor.

If Apache crashes, see in the apache logfile. On your setup, it's probably in something like `C:\xampp\log\error.log` or some such thing.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that don't uncomment the following line：

```
;extension=php_xdebug.dll
```